# UITableView indexPath error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I use UiTableView to show some data from my database. The code is,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...
NSInteger uniqueId = [self.database.arrayColumnNames indexOfObject:@"id"];
NSInteger title = [self.database.arrayColumnNames indexOfObject:@"title"];
NSInteger Name = [self.database.arrayColumnNames indexOfObject:@"Name"];
NSInteger picture = [self.database.arrayColumnNames indexOfObject:@"pictureName"];//3
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: %@",[[self.arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:uniqueId], [[self.arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:title]];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[[self.arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:picture]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"      %@", [[self.arrayInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:bandName]];
return cell;
```

}

And after I ran the code, I got a error,

```
-[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 3 beyond bounds [0 .. 2]
```

I added some breakpoint in this method, and seems like the length of indexPath is 2, and NSInteger of picture is 3, so the error occurred. It is what I thought about this error, but I don't know how to solve it.

Comment: NSlog your self.arrayInfo. IT should contain only three objects and you are trying to access 4th object which causes the crash.

Comment: what is the number of rows that you are returning in `numberOfRowsInSection` delegate?

Comment: @TejaNandamuri Yes, I found out the problem. Thank you.

Comment: @tx2 I know what you mean, but it's not the problem. Thank you all the same.